# C# run Javascript from button click

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a button on my .aspx interstitial page.  When I click it the onClick event fires off and it does a bunch of validations in the code.  I have a javascript function that I need to call/run AFTER these validations are performed.  This javascript function closes the interstitial page.  How can I call the javascript function from my C# code?  I've tried adding a script manager and a client script but neither work.  What else besides these two options do I have?  I'd be willing to use a hack if it works.  Javascript I'm using:

```
javascript:parent.interstitialBox.closeit(); return false
```

Answer (score 1):

On your button click you need to [registerstartupscript.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript.aspx).

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    //Your validation
    string scriptclose = "parent.interstitialBox.closeit(); return false;";  
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "closeScript", scriptclose, true);  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it just blinks at me.  I know the JavaScript works because I have a "close" text link on my page tied to the Javascript function as well and that works.

Comment: Yes.  The entire interstitial page blinks like it tried to do something but nothing happened.

Comment: I'm unable to get put it on my page without error.  It gives me a "error creating control" every time I try to put it on my form.  That's why I was wondering if there was another way to do this besides using the scriptmanager.

Comment: This is the recommended way, I believe you can also place a literal control on your page and set the value to the script text.

Comment: I'll keep working on trying to get the scriptmanager to work.  Thanks for your help!